# парсеры с помощью ООП

Tags: php, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, php7, веб-скрейпинг

Долгое время писал парсеры на PHP в процедурном стиле. Решил теперь все переписать на ООП стиль. В качестве базы прочитал книгу "М. Зандстра PHP - объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования". Прошу дать пару советов по структуре парсера: какие сущности выделить, какое взаимодействие реализовать между классами, какие примерно нужно выделить интерфейсы или абстрактные классы. Просто хочу чтобы с точки зрения ООП все было правильно, рационально. Основная задача парсера такая: заходить на новостной сайт, по определенным правилом выдергивать ссылки на новости. Потом пройтись по новостям и выдернуть оттуда дату, заголовок и текст новости. Таких новостных сайтов туча. Для каждого из них в БД хранятся теги для выдергивания всей необходимой информации.

Comment: А правильно и рационально использовать ООП там, где оно не нужно?

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов, Объясните почему не нужно?

Comment: Это вы как разработчик системы должны обосновывать применение тех или иных технологий :-D

Comment: Ну посмотрите как это сделано в готовых решениях. Вот, например хороший https://github.com/symfony/dom-crawler

Answer (score 1):

Если выборка по каким-то DOM условиям - то для этого уже есть скриптик phpQuery
проводит парсинг по DOM и как раз работает с DOM как с объектами.